# Eclipse/Java/Android Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
[2013-10-05 15:41:30 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lmyjava/awt/datatransfer/DataFlavor;
[2013-10-05 15:41:30 - KoldRainApplicationsSeries] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lmyjava/awt/datatransfer/DataFlavor;
```

I know this is a build path issue,   but I dont know whats wrong with my build path, so here is a screenshot of it

[image]

Comment: goto Order and Export tab and select all check box then clean and run see what happend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since last Android versions you're not supposed to add libraries from the build path, but just copy&paste them into libs folder.

Remove external jars (`activation.jar`, `additional.jar` and `mail.jar`) from your `Build path`, and add them to `libs` folder (you may create the folder if it doesn't exist).

Comment: I had done that, but in that case there was a red exclamation mark over the project name, so I added them here and that error was gone, just so this error can show up

Comment: Could you post the error showed on problems tab going the libs folder way?

Comment: Great it helped :) Btw, if the answer was helpful, please , consider accepting it so that other users could spot the right answer.

Comment: Yeah, I just had to wait for some time limitation to pass and then I was caught up watching Formula 1, but now Im back and I have accepted the answer